# SFML, растягивание спрайтов вместе с окном

Tags: c++, sfml, спрайт

Что нужно сделать, чтобы спрайт не растягивался в месте с окном?

Например, я загружаю текстуру `64 x 64` пикселя, затем создаю спрайт и задаю ему эту текстуру.

Изначально, при отрисовке спрайта, он занимает на окне `64 x 64` пикселя. Если я начну менять размер окна, то размер выводимого изображения будет меняться, он зависит от размеров окна.

Я понимаю, почему это происходит, но как от этого избавиться в SFML - понять не могу.

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php#showing-more-when-the-window-is-resized